# Dbplyr count unique (n_distinct) with case_when or if_else

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I want to create a new column counting unique dates (`dplyr::n_distinct`) with `dplyr::case_when` function using a `dplyr::tbl` *df* object.

I tried the following code:

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(
    last_date = max(date),
    distinct_date_2020 = case_when(
            date >= "2020-01-01" & date <= "2020-12-31" ~ n_distinct(date[!type == "Online"]),
            TRUE ~ as.integer(0))
) %>%
ungroup()
```

The `mutate` of `distinct_date_2020` does not work. I receive the following error message:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.

If I run without the `distinct_date_2020`, it works:

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(
    last_date = max(date)
) %>%
ungroup()
```

I also tried these variants, without success:

```
distinct_date_2020 = n_distinct(date[date >= "2020-01-01" & date <= "2020-12-31" & !type == "Online"])
```

and

```
distinct_date_2020 = ifelse(date >= "2020-01-01" & date <= "2020-12-31", n_distinct(date[!type == "Online"]), NA)
```

If I run these after `collect()`, it works. But I want to send this as a SQL command to the server.

`DBI::dbGetInfo`:

> $dbms.name [1] "Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> $db.version [1] "11.00.6523"

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working. I first grouped by `id`, extracted the last date and then grouped by year (using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`, avoiding the `lubridate` package because of its lack of compatibility with the `dbplyr` package). Summarizing and putting the condition `[type != "Online"]` between brackets also worked. I got the desired results with the code below:

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(
            last_date_temp = max(date)
        ) %>%
    group_by(year = DATEADD(sql("year"), DATEDIFF(sql("year"), 0, date), 0), id) %>%
    summarize(
        last_date = max(last_date_temp, na.rm = TRUE),
        distinct_date = n_distinct(date[type != "Online"]),
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(id, year, everything()) %>%
    arrange(id, year) %>%
    collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is neither with `case_when` nor with `n_distinct` but with square brackets applied to `date`.

Within R, `date[!type == "Online"]` selects a subset of all rows in the column. SQL queries (mostly) work row-by-row, hence requiring the input to `n_distinct` to be a filtering of the date column based on the type column will not produce valid SQL.

One way to test this is with the `show_query` command:

```r
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(
    last_date = max(date),
    distinct_date_2020 = case_when(
            date >= "2020-01-01" & date <= "2020-12-31" ~ n_distinct(date[!type == "Online"]),
            TRUE ~ as.integer(0))
) %>%
ungroup() %>%
show_query()
```

Unless this produces valid SQL code then your query is guaranteed to error.

The solution is to do this filtering separately:

```r
dist_dates = df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(type != "Online",
           date >= "2020-01-01",
           date <= "2020-12-31") %>%
    mutate(distinct_date_2020 = n_distinct(date)) %>%
    ungroup()

max_dates = df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(last_date = max(date))
    ungroup()

output = max_dates %>%
    left_join(dist_dates, by = "id") %>%
    select(id, last_date, distinct_date_2020)
```

I have made the two summaries separately, so that the filter does not apply to `last_date`.

I have removed the `case_when` as in your example it only serves as a filter. But if you want to do it this way try:

```r
dist_dates = df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(type != "Online") %>%
    mutate(
        distinct_date_2020 = case_when(
            date >= "2020-01-01" & date <= "2020-12-31" ~ n_distinct(date),
            TRUE ~ as.integer(0))
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately neither did work when I add `collect()` for computing a `n_distinct` function. If I remove any `n_distinct` function, it works perfectly...

Comment: Does `show_query` produce a valid sql query? (before collecting). It would help if you posted the sql code that does get returned by `show_query` on the solution with all the filtering.

Comment: Another thing to try is `summarise` in place of `mutate`. `n_distinct` may only with within `summarise` not within mutate.